# Could not create client id - DB failure

Tags: jboss, oracle11g

I was trying to start the ATG publishing servers on `JBoss`. From my JBoss bin directory, I used the following command `.\run.bat -c ATGPublishing -b 0.0.0.0`.I was getting the following error. I am using `Oracle 11g`. Any idea why this error is coming up??

```
2013-07-18 10:22:43,025 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.messaging.SqlJmsProvider] (/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler-reusablejobhandler-PATCHBAY-RESTART) could not create client ID for client name Admin-VAIO:8850 : DB failure or maybe the client name already exists in the DB
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

com this side most of you r confusing how to install local dynamo DB here is solutin....

1).download java and install this will goes your c drive program file anyway

2).now download dynaolocalDB and put in that directory where you want to work

3).unzip it

4).now just know where java install i mean path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

5).open cmd (comand prompt) and set java path like set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"

6).now go that dir where you put your dbdynamoDb like C:\developer\node_modules\npm\dbdynamoDb

copy and past this

```
$ java –Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
if error then
java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
still error then specify port
java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -- port8050
```